# Passing Type to generic method

Tags: c#, generics, types

I want to pass a Type to a generic method in C#.

Here's a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

```
    public void myMainMethod()
    {
        Type t = typeof(myClass);
        myGenericMethod<t>();
    }

    public void myGenericMethod<T>()
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

I wish to pass the type held in `t` as the generic method's type. In this case, I get the error "'t' is a variable but used like a type". Should I be using `MakeGenericType` and if so, how?

Comment: See for example [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/232535/555045), however I generally believe that you should avoid doing this as long as that is at all reasonably possible.

Comment: Why can't you pass myClasses's type into the generic method?  You may need to refer to @harold's example for more complex cases dealing with inheritance, polymorphism, etc, but for simple cases passing the class type should work just fine.

Comment: @McFlurry I'm assuming this is a simplified example, where the type `myClass` is determined somewhere else in the app and with more complexity such that it's impossible to determine at compile time.